# Fine Uploader: Uploading Multiple Images in 1 request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, fine-uploader

I have been searching for this but never found a solution yet.

I am using Fine Uploader plugin for Drag and Drop.

**What am I trying to do?**
I have a sign up form for creating a new account and I want to attach his images in the Drag and Drop to the database

**What is the problem?**
When I submit the form, it uploads the images and creates the record, but it creates a record for each images (ex. if he added 4 images it creates 4 records)

So any solution for this?

Comment: Without the code, we are helpless to give solutions to you! Kindly show us what have you tried so far!